# Why the value of the ref object is not the same as the assigned value on the UI, though it is showing the same in the console in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As till the end of `useEffect`, `inputValue` has been assigned to `previousInputValue.current`, and the `useEffect` runs during the rendering or rerendering of the component, so I think `previousInputValue.current` in the 2nd `<h2>` tag also should be same as `inputValue` value. But how is it able to show the previous value?

```
export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const previousInputValue = useRef("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputValue, previousInputValue.current); // ab ab,i think it should be "ab a"
    previousInputValue.current = inputValue;
    console.log("--", inputValue, previousInputValue.current); // ab ab 
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <h2>Current Value: {inputValue}</h2>  {/* ab */}
      <h2>Previous Value: {previousInputValue.current}</h2> {/*a i think it should be ab, as it is assigning inputValue in the useEffect()*/}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me remind you that the callback of an `useEffect` runs after the component is rendered on the page, on mount, and after each change. And only a `setState` call can trigger a new re-render inside a component.

So every time `setInputValue` is called, the UI is updated with `inputValue` equal to the typed text. And **only** after the UI is updated, the callback of the `useEffect` is called, where you do:

```js
previousInputValue.current = inputValue
```

At this point, the two are equal, but the UI won't get updated, because a `ref` update doesn't trigger a re-render.

You would have to wait for then the next input, to have the previous

```
previousInputValue.current = inputValue
```

shown on the screen as the value of `previousInputValue.current`, and the callback of the `useEffect` runs again. This is the behaviour you are seeing.